# JGiT pull hanging

Tags: java, git, eclipse-plugin, chromium, jgit

I am doing git pull by the following commands :

```
Repository localRepo = new FileRepository(file.getAbsolutePath() + "/.git");
final Git git1 = new Git(localRepo);                
PullCommand pullCmd = git1.pull().setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider( "user", "pwd"));
pullCmd.call();
git1.close();
```

When I run this code through eclipse as a java application. It works fine.
But when I export this as an eclipse plugin it hangs.
Note: I am using jcef container to load a url and clicking on a button interacts with jcef and takes pull.

**jgit version 4.11**

Comment: Can you provide a stacktrace via jstack while it is hanging

Comment: There is not stacktrace information coming.
Actually JGIT pull expects some username/password for authentication and should displays a popup asking for the same, which should not be case as I have already send the username and password via code.